# Ocaml inference type int list instead 'a list

Tags: types, ocaml, type-inference

```
let rec getElement list index = match list with
| [] -> raise OutOfBoundException
| first::elems -> if index = 0 then first else getElement elems index-1;;
```

I don't understand why this function has type (int list -> int -> int) instead ('a list -> int -> 'a).
I need to write function that returns nth element in the list, that has generic type (has type exp defined by user: http://pastebin.com/UefshcLa).

How can I write that function? And why Ocaml inferences that list is int list instead 'a list?

Comment: You also can have a look to the function `nth` which do the same job of your function.

Answer (score 10):

OCaml interprets `(getElement elems index) - 1`, because function application is stronger than `-`.

```
let rec getElement list index = match list with
| [] -> raise OutOfBoundException
| first::elems -> if index = 0 then first else getElement elems (index-1);;
```